# Как добавить шлюз в VPN подключение

Tags: windows, сеть, vpn

[image]

Предполагаю, что средствами "`route add` ...."

Comment: Через свойства VPN подключения делать не пробовали?

Comment: Уважаемый, в VPN подключениях такого нету, есть только айпи адрес и днс

Comment: И зачем в VPN прописывать шлюз, если он идёт, по умолчанию, от провайдера? У вас же канал прокинут! Там шлюз от прова, а все эти минипорты НЕ СОЗДАЮТ НОВОГО ФИЗИЧЕСКОГО ИНТЕРФЕЙСА!!!

Comment: шлюз чего? Чего хотите добиться?

Comment: Речь про "Основной шлюз"?

Comment: 1)это не провайдер  а внутренняя сеть с инетом .. необходимо раздать интернет трафик по "входящему соединению" т.е по pptpв winXP это было на ура! а в win 7 ult такого не получается2)нужно добавить шлюз что бы можно было роутить трафик от себя(vpn) до интернета и на оборот

Comment: и да речь про основной шлюз

Answer (score 2):

Правильно предполагаете. После того ка будет установлено VPN запускайте заранее созданный .bat-файл с прописанными локальными (?) маршрутами, что там у Вас (сетевые ресурсы, медиа потоки (IPTV)). Если "route add что_там_у_Вас" в конце строки добавить "-p", винда сделает маршрут постоянным, т.е. не нужно будет прописывать маршруты каждый раз (запускать .bat-файл)

Comment: О, мудрый Каа, я пришел к тебе за советом...ситуация такова что мне нужно из работы конектиться домой по vpn(pptp)и выходить в нет с моим (домашним) айпи. В WinXp такая "цаца" проходит на ура Т.Е. создал входящее подключение пробродил порт через модем и конектимся с работы домой и получаем домашний айпи.В Win 7 ult такое не прокатывает...

Comment: Для этого во всех версиях win есть это http://exe.ho.ua/images/22-03-2013%200-11-12.jpg  "Использовать основной шлюз"

Comment: Основной шлюз и так стоит! а толку то?

Comment: http://www.kerio.com/control/download

Answer (score 0):

Так галочку основного шлюза надо снять или поставить в одном случае инет идет через впн в другой через твой инет.